# Not able to use symbols in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 chart in my project version used is version 4,

My Code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-morning-bi9vc

I am trying to use the triangle symbol in place of my circle in my line chart

code -

```
g.selectAll(".point")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.symbolTriangle)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return (
          "translate(" + xScale(d.startTime) + "," + yScale(d.magnitude) + ")"
        );
      })
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr("class", "point");
```

Previously for circle - this was working fine for circle.

```
g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 6;
      })
```

I have followed this  -

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3244058
to use like `.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))` but this also don’t work.

I tried to refer https://bl.ocks.org/feyderm/4d143591b66725aed0f1855444752fd9 and symbol link https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols but I am not able to use it successfully, Any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, if you uncomment lines 635-637 of your sandbox code it'll work just fine.

Comment: @altocumulus ye because I did the changes to get it working.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-morning-bi9vc @altocumulus can you guide me if I want to have both circle and triangle in line is it possible ? with conditions ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are looking for. That's a new question, though. I suggest you put it in a different post and either delete this one or write a self-answer instead.

Comment: I still maintain I'd rather see this either getting a decent answer or being deleted altogether.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!--TRY Triangle-->
<div id="chart"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var svg_dx = 800, 
        svg_dy = 400,
        margin_x = 100;
        //Triangle shape//
    var shapes = [ 
                   d3.symbolTriangle ];

    var x = d3.scalePoint()
              .domain(d3.range(0, shapes.length))
              .range([margin_x, svg_dx - margin_x]);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", svg_dx)
                .attr("height", svg_dy);

    var symbol = d3.symbol().size([1500]),
        color = d3.schemeCategory10;

    var drag_behavior = d3.drag()
                          .on("start", dragstarted)
                          .on("drag", dragged);
    svg.append("g")
       .selectAll("path")
       .data(shapes)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", symbol.type(shape => shape))
       .attr("transform", (shape, i) => "translate(" + x(i) + ", -40)")
       .style("fill", (shape, i) => color[i])
       .call(drag_behavior)
       .transition()
       .duration((shape, i) => i * 800)
       .attr("transform", (shape, i) => "translate(" + x(i) + "," + (svg_dy / 2) + ")");

    function dragstarted() {
      d3.select(this).raise();
    }

    function dragged(shape) {

        var dx = d3.event.sourceEvent.offsetX,
            dy = d3.event.sourceEvent.offsetY;

        d3.select(this)
          .attr("transform", shape => "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")");
    }

</script>
```

[D3 v4 shapes](https://bl.ocks.org/feyderm/4d143591b66725aed0f1855444752fd9)

Comment: I am using `.attr(
        "d",
        d3.svg
          .symbol()
          .size(81)
          .type("triangle-up")
      )` but this should work i feel. there is some issue with version ?

Comment: You shared the same link what i referred.